# Bash get last line from a variable

Tags: bash, variables, line

If I have a variable with multiple lines (text) in it, how can I get the last line out of it?

I already figured out how to get the first line:

```
STRING="This is a
multiple line
variable test"
FIRST_LINE=(${STRING[@]})
echo "$FIRST_LINE"

# output:
"This is a"
```

Probably there should be an operator for the last line. Or at least I assume that because with `@` the first line comes out.

Comment: Your script output is only first word of variable (This), not all line.

Comment: Oh, didn't get that. Maybe because in my use case the first line is only a single word. *phew*

Comment: If you need to do such manipulations, don't store the lines in a string but in an array!

Comment: `STRING` is not an array, so `${STRING[@]}` isn't really any different from `$STRING`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using bash string manipulations:

```
$> str="This is a
multiple line
variable test"

$> echo "${str##*$'\n'}"
variable test
```

`${str##*$'\n'}` will remove the longest match till `\n` from start of the string thus leaving only the last line in input.

Answer (score 81):

An easy way to do this is to use `tail`:

```
echo "$STRING" | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array with one element per line from `STRING`, use

```
readarray -t lines <<< "$STRING"
```

Then, the first line would be `${lines[0]}`, and the last line would be `${lines[-1]}`. In older versions of `bash`, negative indices aren't allowed and you'll have to compute the last index manually: `${lines[${#lines[@]}-1]}`.

Comment: A small note may be stating need `bash 4.x`?

Comment: IMO, 3.x should just be treated as a POSIX-compatible shell on par with `dash`, but with better features for interactive use. I consider the nearly 6-year-old `bash` 4.2 release a reasonable baseline assumption now.

Comment: Still using `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`  btw :), in which it is not supported. :( Thought would be good point to add for a proper reference.

Comment: I also consider knowing what version of `bash` you are using to be part of your due diligence in asking a question. I am no longer presenting a laundry list of options to cater to 3 or more different versions of `bash` in every answer. I'm taking Python as my model, where the assumption is that you are using Python 3.3+ unless otherwise stated, and Python 2 pretty much means Python 2.7.

Comment: Cheers! no disrespect meant!

Comment: None taken! This is a little rant that's been building in me for some time, and there's no good place for it :) I'd love to get some consensus and put a note in the `bash` tag info about what features we can reasonably assume, but no one asking questions reads that page anyway.